# Webcam FPS Very Low

Tags: usb, webcam, chromium

I just plugged in a Microsoft Lifecam Studio webcam into my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.  I used gucview to test it out along with Google Hangouts for video conferencing (in Chromium) but the FPS was terribly low (e.g. 6 FPS) despite high FPS settings.  Any ideas on how to increase the FPS from a webcam?

Comment: Hi @Ryan, Ah, let me see. Usually under 30 fps is unacceptable.  I once played Rpi3 with two cheap Logitech webcam at low resolution, eg 480x 320 BW and could do 30 fps for simple pattern recognition app. If you are using 4k 64k colours, of course very slow!  You might set high res, high fps, but the system would fall back to a lower config, if can't cope. BTW, my Google Plus account seems closed some months ago, and I thought Google Hangouts also closed.  So it is still alive!